# How could I truncate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate, slim-lang

I have this following code

```
= simple_format(h auto_link(work.body.truncate(140)))
```

Trying to truncate the body text. But this gives me error.
How could I make truncate work in this kind of occasion?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Code seems to be working, might be something to do with the string you are passing to the truncate method or it may be because of the outside method is the culprit of causing issues.Please post your error to identify solution

Comment: Is your body consist html tags ???

Comment: post your error as well

Comment: Make sure body is not `nil`

Comment: It just shows blank page on production so I can't really look at the error. My body text can't include tags but do have URL's in them sometimes. Some body could be nil... is that why its showing the error?

Comment: Kindly explain your question well. Are you getting an Error or the problem is you are not getting the required functionality?